# Verify access tokens from multiple front end apps (client ID) using okta-jwt-verifier

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, jwt, okta

We have 2 front end apps(angular) using the same backend api. Is it possible to send in an array of clientIds, so we can verify access tokens generated from multiple applications?

```
const OktaJwtVerifier = require("@okta/jwt-verifier");
const oktaJwtVerifier = new OktaJwtVerifier({
  issuer: 'https://my-okta-domain/oauth2/default',
  clientId: '',
});

module.exports = function oktaAuthorization(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization || "";
  const match = authHeader.match(/Bearer (.+)/);
  const accessToken = match ? match[1] : "";
  return oktaJwtVerifier
    .verifyAccessToken(accessToken, "api://default")
    .then((jwt) => {
      req.app.locals.loggedInUser = jwt.claims.sub;
      next();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send("unauthorized");
      res.status(401).send("unauthorized");
    });
};
```

FYI- both apps are able to connect to the backend api when I use their client ID, the issuer or the authorization url is same for both

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking `client_id` is not required to verify an access token with this library. If you perform validation on your back-end server, it does not matter, which client obtained the token as long as the audience is correct. But I see that you are using `api://default` which makes it bit broader than you probably would like.

What I'd do in this situation - create a custom authZ server and move your apps under it, so that what I told in the prev paragraph would hold. Then you are free to add as many clients to your back-end service, as longs as they all are sharing the same audience